# Appending the elements of a list whose indices are indices of a certain integer in a different list

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.5

Below is my faulty code:

```
   n = int(input())
   coins = list(map(int,input().split()))
   workertype = list(map(int,input().split()))
   a1 = []
   a2 = []
   a3 = []
   for i in range(n):
     if(workertype[i]==1):
       a1.append(coins[i])

   elif(workertype[i]==2):
      a2.append(coins[i])

   elif(workertype[i]==3):
      a3.append(coins[i])
   print(a1,a2,a3)
```

`coins` and `workertype` are two lists of equal length. I want list `a1` to have those elements of list `coins` whose indices are the one at which `1`(all 1's) is present in list `workertype`.
Same for `a2` and `a3` but for all `2`s and `3`s.

***this is my output***

```
    1(#input for n)
    5 6 7 5 9 10 8(#coins)
    1 2 3 3 2 2 1(#workertype)
    [5] [] [](a1, a2, a3)
```

Instead of this I wanted a1, a2, a3 to be [5,1], [6,9,10], [7,5] respectively.

Comment: why don't you make `a` a list of lists so you can use the index directly? why asking for `n` when `coins` and `workertype` must have at least n elements (but is not checked)?

Comment: what is your exact input & error?

Comment: your indentation is off- can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49761287/edit) your question and fix it?

Comment: Why would it add more than the first element if `n` is 1?

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you enter 7 (the length of coins and workertype) as n.

Comment: oh my bad. I was confused. Thank you!